# Instagram resource loaded in android WebView and copy the link of resource?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-webview

I want to copy the link of the Instagram video in which the user clicks on the resource which is loaded in android web view the same thing I implemented for Facebook but it's working fine. I almost search for two days but I do not find any answer if anyone knows please correct me.

Here is my code for Instagram web Client.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                urlString=url;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { "
                        + "var el = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-sigil]');"
                        + "for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++)"
                        + "{"
                        + "var sigil = el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                        + "if(sigil.indexOf('inlineVideo') > -1){"
                        + "delete el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                        + "var jsonData = JSON.parse(el[i].dataset.store);"
                        + "el[i].setAttribute('onClick', 'IGDownloader.processVideod(\"'+jsonData['src']+'\");');"
                        + "}" + "}" + "})()");
                Log.e("WEBVIEWFIN", url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function prepareVideo() { "
                        + "var el = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-sigil]');"
                        + "for(var i=0;i<el.length; i++)"
                        + "{"
                        + "var sigil = el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                        + "if(sigil.indexOf('inlineVideo') > -1){"
                        + "delete el[i].dataset.sigil;"
                        + "console.log(i);"
                        + "var jsonData = JSON.parse(el[i].dataset.store);"
                        + "el[i].setAttribute('onClick', 'IGDownloader.processVideod(\"'+jsonData['src']+'\",\"'+jsonData['videoID']+'\");');"
                        + "}" + "}" + "})()");
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:( window.onload=prepareVideo;"
                        + ")()");

            }
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url) {
                
                if(url.equals("http://stackoverflow.com/questions")){
                    Toast.makeText(InstagramView.this,"No url",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(InstagramView.this,temp,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return  false;
            }
        });
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
        }
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
        webView.loadUrl(instaURL);
    }
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I did not find the solution.